# Set attribute with JS and grab it by controlID in code-behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

After postback, attributes are cleared.

So how can I send an attribute applied to controlID via JS to the next request page?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Javascript and ASP.Net controls can have a rather strained relationship. The main thing to remember is that ASP.Net needs to be able to get a value/see a change. Custom attributes may not be kept during a post back.

Have you tried storing the info using a hidden control?

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="id" Value="value" />
```

[MSDN ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield.aspx)

Comment: Hello cofiem and thx for your short reply.

That would be a possibility - But since I would like to keep things in order and together I would prefer having it in the object and it's attributes.

This is because it actually is a JS-script that checks forms and here there is a drop-down list and a manual entering TextField, one replaces the other ..

When you focus the TextField it will of course set disabled="disabled" which is why I would see an advantage by grabbing that property in the code-behind on the submit button.

Comment: you should be able to get the value of `disabled` server-side using `.Enabled`. Most other attributes can be accessed. What attribute are you trying to get that isn't available? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox(VS.90).aspx

Comment: Exactly.

But if JS is used to apply .disabled it will not be available serverside.

Any attribute I add via JS will never be visible serverside. Not even if I put an empty title="" via ctrl.Attributes.Add("title",""); ..

I really can't believe this is not something which ASP.NET has implemented yet and can be done with relatively easy approach. This just can't be!!